# How can I send Hebrew text to SQL Server from a C# ASP.NET parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

When `words_array[i]` is Hebrew text, the database shows `'?????'` in place of the word.

```
myCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MyTable(word) VALUES (@word);
myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@word", SqlDbType.Varchar, 50));
command.Parameters["@word"].Value = words_array[i];
```

I tried below, but got an error :

> Incorrect syntax near 'N'

My attempt:

```
myCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MyTable(word) VALUES (N'@word'N);
```

I tried this, too - problem: placed the text '@word' in place of the Hebrew word.

```
myCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MyTable(word) VALUES (N'@word');
```

Comment: `SqlDbType.Varchar` ??? That line tells SQL Server to treat the parameter as ASCII instead of Unicode. Use `NVarchar` instead. Neither SQL Server nor ASP.NET have any problems with Unicode and SO itself proves it - it's an ASP.NET web app storing text in a SQL Server database

Comment: Thank You! Solved!

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: Side note: you can use shorter syntax `myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@word", SqlDbType.NVarchar, 50)).Value = words_array[i];` also if you are inserting in bulk, consider using a Table Parameter, or using `SqlBulkCopy` both of which are much faster

Answer (score 1):

Change `SqlDbType.VarChar` with `SqlDbType.NVarChar`. There's no need to prefix strings when using parameterized queries.

The line :

```
myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@word",SqlDbType.VarChar,50));
```

Says that the parameter's type is a string using a single-byte codepage instead of a Unicode string. Strings in .NET are Unicode but this line tells the driver to convert the value to a single-byte encoding using the codepage specified by the thread's `CurrentCultureInfo`.

It should be

```
myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@word",SqlDbType.NVarChar,50));
```